# How to stop this parent element from being affected on hover?

Tags: html, css

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fp5TM/)

When you hover over one of the first links (products,technology, etc), a dropdown menu appears and the link turns orange. It continues to stay orange as you hover over the dropdown menu. I remember doing something for it to behave this way, and I want to get rid of it now, but I cannot for the life of me remember how I did this, and cannot undo it. Anyone see how I can undo this?

Here's the css:

```
#navbar{
    list-style: none; 
    float: right; 
    margin-top: 54px; 
    position: relative;
}

.firstnavmenu{
    margin-top: 10px; 
}

/*first level*/
#navbar li{
    float:left; 
    width: 140px;
    text-align: center; 
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: background 0.3s ease;
    transition: background 0.3s ease;
}

#navbar li a{
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif; 
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 1px; 
    color: #524F4F; 
    font-weight: 600; 
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: color 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: color 0.3s ease;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#navbar li:hover > a{
    color: #f3a82e; 
}

#navbar li:hover > ul{
    height: 250px;
}

/* second level */
#navbar li ul{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;    
    height:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

#navbar li ul li:last-child{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}

#navbar li ul li{
    float: none; 
    position: relative;
    width: 140px; 
    height: auto;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#navbar li ul li a{
    padding-left: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 6px; 
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;  
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

than use

```
#navbar li a:hover{
    color: #f3a82e; 
}
```

instead of this

```
#navbar li:hover > a{
    color: #f3a82e; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fp5TM/1/